# Equivalence relations and classes

Tags: equivalence-relations

$T$ is defined on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ by $(a,b)\mathrel{T}(c,d)$ if and only if $a \leq c$ and $b \leq d$.

I know this is a partial order relation as it is Transitive, Anti Symmetric and Reflexive but I'm not sure if its total order relation and whether they are well order relations?

Comment: try compare $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a total order: just compare $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. It is a well partial order, a result known as [Dickson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma).

Comment: Im assuming a well order relation is different from a well partial order? As I don't think we have learnt Dickson's Lemma yet

Comment: @Sunny. Look at the first sentence of [this page on Well orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) : *In mathematics, a well-order relation (or well-ordering)...*  As a rule, please look at Wikipedia before asking any question on math.stackexchange.